# Bulk copy export in SQL using queryout

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I am testing a simple syntax for Bulk Copy export - Output file is a Flat File with tab delimiter (either in SQL Server 2008 or 2012).

Somehow my command is throwing a syntax error on `queryout`:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM DatabaseLog" queryout "C:\Test\TestingBulkCopy.txt" -t\t -c -T
```

Answer (score 0):

BCP is a command-line utility. You need to run it for an OS command prompt rather than from a T-SQL session.

Comment: If i have to run from OS Command prompt then, i will have to pass the SQL authentication details  in the syntax ??

Comment: Is there a way to run the BCP from the SQL Session ?

Comment: @goofyui, you could do that using `xp_cmdshell`. The question though is why you would need/want to. There are security concerns with going down that path.